# Calculating the position of a point on a circle knowing the value of the point on the Y axis

Tags: geometry

How can I calculate the value of `Bx` knowing the radius of the circle, the `x` and `y` values of point `A` and the value of `By`?

[image: position of By]

I'll probably need to calculate both of the intersecting points on the grey line and select the one with the highest value.

Comment: This question is not answerable without knowing the radius of the circle.

Comment: Sorry, that's a given indeed. I modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the radius of the circle $R$. The segment from $A$ to $B$ is the hypotenuse of a right triangle. Thus,
$$
R^2 = (B_x-A_x)^2+(B_y-A_y)^2
$$
Solving this for $B_x$ gives
$$
B_x = A_x \pm \sqrt{R^2 - (B_y-A_y)^2}
$$
Since you always want the larger one, this is simply
$$
B_x = A_x + \sqrt{R^2 - (B_y-A_y)^2}
$$

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! That's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

If the radius of the circle is $R$, then $R$ is the distnce between $(A_x,A_y)$ and $(B_x,B_y)$, or,
$$R^2=(100-60)^2+(100-B_x)^2$$
This is a quadratic in $B_x$, solving which you will get two roots $B_{x1}$ and $B_{x2}$. Then $(B_{x1},B_y)$ and $(B_{x1},B_y)$ are two end points of the chord. Choose the root that is greater than $A_x=100$, that will be your $B_x$.