# Calculating an intersection point of two circles

Tags: geometry

In continuation of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278361/calculating-the-position-of-a-point-on-a-circle-knowing-the-value-of-the-point-o/2278384#2278384), I would like to calculate the position of an intersection point on two circles, knowing the radius and centre position point of both.

[image]

Comment: If you know the radius and the center you know the formula for each. $(x-0)^2+(y-100)^2=55^2$ and $(x-140)^2+(y-100)^2=115^2$    If you know the formula for each find a mutual solution to both. $x=\pm{55^2 - (y-100)^2}$ .. etc.  You'll get two sets of answers.  The one with the higher value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

circle $(\mathcal C_1)$ : $(x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 = r_1^2$

circle $(\mathcal C_2)$ : $(x-x_2)^2 + (y-y_2)^2 = r_2^2$

Intersecting points belongs to the line $(\mathcal D)$ : $ax + by = c$ obtained by calculating $(\mathcal C_2)-(\mathcal C_1)$

$\begin{array}{l}
a = 2(x_2-x_1)\\
b = 2(y_2-y_1)\\
c = r_1^2 - r_2^2 + x_2^2 - x_1^2 + y_2^2 - y_1^2
\end{array}$

### $a=b=0$ : concentric circles

So depending wether the radius are equal or not, we have zero or the full circle intersection.

### $a=0$ : $(\mathcal D)$ is a vertical line

$\begin{array}{ll}
d = r_1^2 - (y-y_1)^2 & \text{If $d<0$ there are no intersection points}\\
x = x_1\pm\sqrt{d}\\
y = \frac cb\\
\end{array}$

### $b=0$ : $(\mathcal D)$ is an horizontal line

$\begin{array}{l}
d = r_1^2 - (x-x_1)^2 & \text{If $d<0$ there are no intersection points}\\
x = \frac ca\\
y = y_1\pm\sqrt{d}\\
\end{array}$

### General case, parametric equation for $(\mathcal D)$

$(\mathcal D)$ : $\begin{cases} x = x_0 - t\\ y = mt\end{cases}\quad$ with $\quad x_0 = \frac ca\quad$ and $\quad m = \frac ab$

Carry back in $(\mathcal C_1)$ to find an equation for $t$ : $A\,t^2 -2B\,t + C = 0$

$\begin{array}{ll}
A = 1 + m^2\\
B = (x_0-x_1) + my_1\\
C = (x_0-x_1)^2 + y_1^2 - r_1^2\\
D = B^2 - AC & \text{If $D<0$ there are no intersection points}\\
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{l}
t = \frac{B\pm\sqrt{D}}{A}\\
x = x_0-t\\
y = mt\\
\end{array}$

Answer (score 2):

The equation of circle A is $x^2 + (y-100)^2 = 55^2$, and that of circle B is $(x-140)^2 + (y-100)^2 = 115^2$, so solving these simultaneously gives $x = \frac{235}{7}$, and hence $y = 100 \pm \frac{10\sqrt{930}}{7}$, giving solution points at around $(33.57, 143.57)$, $(33.57, 56.43)$, to two decimal places.